# Cannot get traffic when setting up transparent proxy mode for specific port

Tags: linux, proxy, iptables, mitmproxy, transparentproxy

I'd like to capture a HTTP service call from HostA -> HostB to test the client on HostA. Both OS are Linux. I tried following but fail.
What's the recommended way to do this?

I would like to use transparent proxy mode because I cannot modify client and cannot redirect all traffic from HostA to hostB as other service also running on HostA. I'd like only redirect the connection of the client from host A to host B.
The client in Host A call a service on Host B on a certain port 10001 by HTTP.

I tried setup HostC with mitmproxy  (HostA and HostC are in the same subnet)
HostA (ip_A) -> HostC(ip_C) with mitmproxy-> HostB(ip_B) , I set the ip table to build transparent mode.

Following is what I setup for on HostA

```
sudo iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10001 -j MARK --set-mark 1
sudo ip route add default via ip_C table 100
sudo ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table 100
```

On HostC

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 10001 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
mitmproxy -T --host
```

This doesn't work.  client on HostA connection timeout.
If I try traceroute on HostA

```
traceroute ip_B -p 10000 -T
```

It shows ip_B is unreachable on TCP from HostA

I also tried setup mitmproxy on HostA, but  when I try to redirect traffic of port 10001 
on HostA

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10001 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
mitmproxy -T --host
```

The service call could be capture by mitmproxy on HostA but cannot get response.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for coding-related questions, your question should be asked at https://superuser.com.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.